# Please identify this unusual jump plane

Tags: aircraft-identification, skydiving

Can anyone identify this aircraft:[image]

This plane was used in a horrible skydiving attempt where the person in the back attempted to climb out but was unable. As a skydiver, this made me very uncomfortable. I am guessing there is a large tail on this aircraft that would have made exiting fatal. The full video is here:

Comment: You sure that video is not fake?

Comment: The plane appears to be real.

Comment: I guess I would just like to believe that no one would stick their hand into the engine intake of an airborne fighter jet ...

Comment: The camera wobble looks weird to me. A camera fixed to the wing shouldn't move around like that. But it could be a result of image stabilization

Comment: The camera could have been a 360 camera, but we're only seeing a narrow field of the view (which is kept pointing the same way relative to the horizon by stabilization). I've seen this done a lot with RC plane videos.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That is an [Aero L-29 Delfin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aero_L-29_Delf%C3%ADn)

[image]

Source: onespotter, photographer/copyright: [Evgeniy Lebedev](https://onespotter.com/profile/7268)

Comment: Good job. I spent 40 minutes trying to identify it without any success!

Comment: @ThatCoolCoder I got lucky. My first guess was something similar to the hawker hunter. Then I noticed the Russian flag on the nose and the name Peaktopw (?). Putting "peaktopw jet" into google image search gave one image with a jet. This one :-) . The aircraft is part of the Reactors Jetteam (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VRndI5CVqNo)

Comment: @DeltaLima: I'm not Russian, but the word 'peaktop' is 'reactor' written in Russian. P in cyrillic alphabet represents 'R' in latin alphabet. Also, 'K' is used for hard 'C' because in the cyrillic alphabet, 'C' is the equivalent of 'S'. The w at the end is I guess some representation of another cyrillic character which looks like 'bl'. That one is a bit tricky to explain, as it's not actually a letter. Look it up on wikipedia if you want to go down the rabbit hole :-).

Comment: @Gaston thank you for the explanation. It makes sense to me now. Went down the Ы-hole this morning already :-)

Comment: Awesome job. I am going to do some research and see if anyone has ever successfully jumped out of one. It does not look possible from my perspective.

Comment: @SDH I guess the backseater realised too that it wasn't looking positive when he was upside down hanging from the cockpit with his legs still inside and his hand in the jet intake while the aircraft was vibrating from his turbulence. One-of-a-kind type of experience.

Comment: @Gaston the word is "реакторы" - "reactor**s**" in English. The last letter is actually a real letter even with its own corresponding sound (unlike similarly looking "Ь"). In this particular case it makes a plural  noun from a singular "реактор", similarly to "-s" in English.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Sorry my bad. Thanks for the clarification, yes I mixed it up with 'Ь'